# How do I create a subset of previously surveyed areas which covers all survey teams and land class types?

Tags: r

I am currently only working with dummy data (attached) but the situation is:

- I will have a high number of different original survey areas (in dummy data, 100)
- Each original survey area will have been surveyed by a survey team (in my dummy data, I have included 5 different survey teams: a, b, c, d, e)
- Each survey area has also been allocated a land class type (in my dummy data, I have included 9 land classes: 1 - 9)

I want to write a script which will identify a certain number (for examples sake, let's say 25%) of survey areas for me to resurvey for quality assurance. These identified areas for resurvey must:

- Evenly (as much as possible) cover all survey teams (i.e. 5 per team)
  AND as a subset of that
- Evenly (as much as possible) cover all land classes

Is this possible within R? Or an alternate system? I have access to AGOL and ArcPRO too.

Dummy data:

```
Completed survey area | Survey team |Land Class
1   a   1
2   b   2
3   c   3
4   d   4
5   e   5
6   a   6
7   b   7
8   c   8
9   d   9
10  e   1
11  a   2
12  b   3
13  c   4
14  d   5
15  e   6
16  a   7
17  b   8
18  c   9
19  d   1
20  e   2
21  a   3
22  b   4
23  c   5
24  d   6
25  e   7
26  a   8
27  b   9
28  c   1
29  d   2
30  e   3
31  a   4
32  b   5
33  c   6
34  d   7
35  e   8
36  a   9
37  b   1
38  c   2
39  d   3
40  e   4
41  a   5
42  b   6
43  c   7
44  d   8
45  e   9
46  a   1
47  b   2
48  c   3
49  d   4
50  e   5
51  a   6
52  b   7
53  c   8
54  d   9
55  e   1
56  a   2
57  b   3
58  c   4
59  d   5
60  e   6
61  a   7
62  b   8
63  c   9
64  d   1
65  e   2
66  a   3
67  b   4
68  c   5
69  d   6
70  e   7
71  a   8
72  b   9
73  c   1
74  d   2
75  e   3
76  a   4
77  b   5
78  c   6
79  d   7
80  e   8
81  a   9
82  b   1
83  c   2
84  d   3
85  e   4
86  a   5
87  b   6
88  c   7
89  d   8
90  e   9
91  a   1
92  b   2
93  c   3
94  d   4
95  e   5
96  a   6
97  b   7
98  c   8
99  d   9
100 e   1
```

I am yet to try anything as not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what your after? I created a larger example dataset (n = 10,000) as the example dataset you gave was I believe too small to get the result you're wanting. Note also that due to the distribution of the "Survey team" values relative to "Land Class", slightly more than 25% of survey sites are returned:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
# set.seed() to make results below reproducible
set.seed(1)

# Example df based on values given in your example df
df <- data.frame(`Completed survey area` = 1:10000,
                 `Survey team` = rep(letters[1:5], 2000),
                 `Land Class` = c(rep(1:9, 1111), 1),
                 check.names = FALSE)

# Return ~25% sample of dataset with even distribution of teams and land classes
resurvey <- df %>%
  group_by(`Survey team`, `Land Class`) %>%
  sample_frac(size=.25) # Sample size as fraction of total dataset e.g. 25%

resurvey
# # A tibble: 2,520 × 3
# # Groups:   Survey team, Land Class [45]
# `Completed survey area` `Survey team` `Land Class`
#                   <int>         <chr>        <dbl>
# 1                  3016             a            1
# 2                  7471             a            1
# 3                  5761             a            1
# 4                  7246             a            1
# 5                  9631             a            1
# 6                  1891             a            1
# 7                   586             a            1
# 8                  9406             a            1
# 9                  8371             a            1
# 10                 2251             a            1
# # … with 2,510 more rows# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

# Check sample distribution
check <- resurvey %>% group_by(`Survey team`,`Land Class`) %>% tally()
print(check, n = nrow(check))
# # A tibble: 45 × 3
# # Groups:   Survey team [5]
# `Survey team`     `Land Class`   n
# <chr>                  <dbl> <int>
# 1 a                        1    56
# 2 a                        2    56
# 3 a                        3    56
# 4 a                        4    56
# 5 a                        5    56
# 6 a                        6    56
# 7 a                        7    56
# 8 a                        8    56
# 9 a                        9    56
# 10 b                       1    56
# 11 b                       2    56
# 12 b                       3    56
# 13 b                       4    56
# 14 b                       5    56
# 15 b                       6    56
# 16 b                       7    56
# 17 b                       8    56
# 18 b                       9    56
# 19 c                       1    56
# 20 c                       2    56
# 21 c                       3    56
# 22 c                       4    56
# 23 c                       5    56
# 24 c                       6    56
# 25 c                       7    56
# 26 c                       8    56
# 27 c                       9    56
# 28 d                       1    56
# 29 d                       2    56
# 30 d                       3    56
# 31 d                       4    56
# 32 d                       5    56
# 33 d                       6    56
# 34 d                       7    56
# 35 d                       8    56
# 36 d                       9    56
# 37 e                       1    56
# 38 e                       2    56
# 39 e                       3    56
# 40 e                       4    56
# 41 e                       5    56
# 42 e                       6    56
# 43 e                       7    56
# 44 e                       8    56
# 45 e                       9    56
```

One observation: I would recommend using syntactically valid column names - e.g. avoid spaces and special characters - that way you don't have to use back ticks every time you declare a column name.

Comment: Yes that seems to have done what I am after! Thank you very much